# Integration test values are inserted to database

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing

I am trying to test a JpaRepository with spring boot integration tests. I'm using the @DataJPATest annotation without the embedded db. I'm using the same MySQL db that I use for development to run integration tests.

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE)
class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    void findByUsername() {
        User u = new User();
        u.setUsername("ML");
        u.setFirstname("Micheal");
        u.setLastname("Lane");
        u.setActive(true);
        userRepository.save(u);
        assertThat(userRepository.findByUsername("M21")).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

The value I inserted in the test is inserted into the actual data base. But I thought with @DataJpaTest the transaction is rolled back at the end of the test.

> By default, tests annotated with @DataJpaTest are transactional and roll back at the end of each test. They also use an embedded in-memory database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured DataSource). The @AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation can be used to override these settings.

So why is my data getting saved to the database? Is it because I'm not using the embedded database?

Dialect used : spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

**********************************************************8

It started to rollback once I remove findByUsername() part form the test method

```
 User u = new User();
        u.setUsername("ML");
        u.setFirstname("Micheal");
        u.setLastname("Lane");
        u.setActive(true);
        userRepository.save(u);
        //assertThat(userRepository.findByUsername("M21")).isNotNull();
```

So I guess It doesn't work because there are 2 queries. I will have to use an already saved data for findByUsername() test

Comment: which dialect are you using? Can you post it in question? Also spring version.

Comment: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is due to the auto-wire. When you auto-wire it instantiates the interface via dependency injections. If you don't want data to be stored when running the test I suggest you look at [mockito](https://site.mockito.org/). There you can mock the repos so you can test all the methods used when storing data but never actually saves it

Comment: I don't think so, if you mock the repository you lose the goal of your tests. The goal is to test the repository not to mock it. I will suggest to use an in-memory database.

Comment: @akuma8 but even with the mock you still test the code in the repo.

Comment: When we mock we can influence the result of a method, we do no longer call the actual method implementation.

Comment: I don't want to use an in memory database. I'm trying to connect it an external database.

Comment: @UserR im sorry so you want to connect to the database but dont want to save the said document?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the second time I run this test, it will give an exception because, username is a unique value.

Comment: @UserR Im not sure. like I said I would mock it, this way you test the repo code but you just never save it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by using this dialect.

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Hope this should work.